# DNS Server configuration not Working

Tags: dns

I have a Huawei HG8245H5 router and I want to edit the DNS server settings but the input field seems to not accept user input. Is there any way I could fix that?

Hereby a screenshot:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xr6Vd.png]

Any one has an idea??

Comment: Why do you have `DHCP Relay` enabled? With it enabled, I'm surprised _any_ fields accept user input... (though also it's odd that there is no field to indicate where the requests are being relayed to)

Comment: Thank you for the response. Though, I disabled DHCP Relay and the input field is still disabled..